# Rails: Adding options to collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, form-helpers

I am using a collection_select field, but need to prepend the options with some default one, wich does not represent a particular model record and is used to set the appropriet field to NULL. But I just can't find any way to do that.

If you need any more information, don't hasitate to ask.
Using Rails 3.2.3 with standard form helpers.

P.S. I know I can do something like this:

```
@parents = ['default_name','nil']
@parents << Model.all.map {|item| [item.name,item.id]}
```

But I think there is a more elegant way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is an :include_blank option you can pass to [collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) helper method:

```
f.collection_select(:author_id, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial,
                    :include_blank => "Nothing selected")
```

There is also a similar option called :prompt, check it out too.

Comment: Combination of `:prompt` and `:include_blank` is really clean, instead of a custom `select`. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

You can probably use **select** instead :

```
f.select(:item_id, @items.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] } + ['Or create a new one like','new'], {:include_blank => 'Please select a item'})
```

Comment: This was just what I needed, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this is acceptable in your view?

```
collection_select :field1, :field2, @models+[Model.new(name: "default_name")], :name, :id
```